# What is the best way to send a request over nodeJS TLS Socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, tls1.2

what's the best way to send an HTTP Request over the TLS Socket.

In Example:

A TLS Server sends an HTTP get the request to a TLS Client over the TLS Socket.
The Client sends a response to the server.

Like Server says: Is everything ok, client?
And the Client answer with: Yes everything is perfect!

Comment: A HTTP server does not send a request to a client but a client sends a request to the server - that's how HTTP and HTTPS work.

Comment: I think you missunderstood me. If the TLS Server needs Information from the client like a serialnumber or other information the server send a http request to the client and the client send back the information to server.

I've started with this example: [link]h(ttps://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/253)

It work's fine but if I implent a socket.write() in the 
`.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(data);
})`

function the client steps into a endless loop. I can handle this if I add a identifier to the message so that the client can ignore the request which send by himself.

Comment: You explicitly ask about HTTP request and in HTTP it is the client which sends the request and the server which sends the response. The example you refer to does not use HTTP but a plain TCP or TLS socket. And while you can define your own protocol where the message look like HTTP and the server might send a request to the client which looks like a HTTP request it would still not be HTTP since it might reuse the syntax but does not implement the semantics of the HTTP protocol.

Comment: My solution is maybe not the best but it work's realy fine. The Server send a string of the request to the client.like 

`socket.write('GET /rest/api HTTP/1.1')` 

On the client side I parse the string with the nodejs http-string-parser and send back a response to the server. Before I send the repsponse to the Server I add in the header client: true. I can ignore those messages on the client side. The Server parse the response also with the nodejs http-string-parser.

Comment: While this looks a bit like a HTTP request it is neither a syntactically correct HTTP request nor does it have the semantics defined by HTTP. Essentially you use your own protocol and call it HTTP even though it does not match the HTTP standard.